# How to push docker image to Amazon ECR using io.fabric8 maven plugin with authorization

Tags: amazon-ecs, fabric8

I have a plugin to create a image, once created it need to be pushed to amazon ECR
Please look into my plugin in the below`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
   <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
   <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.24.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <dockerHost>https://accountID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</dockerHost>
      <authConfig>
         <authToken>authorization Token</authToken>
         <username>Access Key ID</username>
         <password>Secret Key Id</password>
      </authConfig>
      <images>
         <image>
            <alias>service</alias>
            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
            <build>
               <from>openjdk:8-jdk-alpine</from>
               <entryPoint>
                  <exec>
                     <arg>java</arg>
                     <arg>-jar</arg>
                     <arg>maven/app.jar</arg>
                  </exec>
               </entryPoint>
               <assembly>
                  <descriptorRef>artifact-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </assembly>
            </build>
         </image>
      </images>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>docker-build</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

`

I have tried with above plugin with authorization token as authtoken . when i am running maven build getting not authorized .

Help will be appreciated

Thanks,
Damodar

Comment: Could you please share the error logs also? Are you running `docker:push` if i'm not wrong..

Comment: Thanks, i have written application to push the image to aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AWS ECR credential helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper)

Please read the documentation for further details, but here are the major steps to get it working:

1. **AWS credentials are set up** (e.g. ~/.aws/credentials)
2. **install the ECR credential helper**
3. **Adapt your ~/.docker/config.json** (for us it has been the second mentioned option with specific aws account id)

```
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "accountID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
  },
  ... (already existing stuff in my setup)
}
```

4. **Use correct environment variables** in the shell where the fabric8 maven-docker-plugin is executed:

```
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true
AWS_PROFILE=your_aws_profile
```

Maybe you will need to define *AWS_REGION* as environment variable as well.

Now when running the maven build, the ECR credential helper should take care of the authentication process, so the "authConfig"-part of the config in the question can be removed.