# How to push docker images to AWS ECR using fabric8 maven plugin while pulling base images from default registry?

Tags: aws-ecr, fabric8-maven-plugin

When configurating the *fabric8 maven plugin to push docker images to AWS ECR*, we get an **error that the "alpine:latest" image cannot be pulled**.

Here the relevant part from the maven pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <registry>your_aws_id.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com</registry>
    <images>
      <image>
        <name>%a:%v-%t</name>
        <build>
          <from>alpine:latest</from>
          <maintainer>a_company_or_person</maintainer>
          ...
        </build>
      </image>
    </images>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to configure the maven fabric8 plugin to push docker images to AWS ECR while pulling from default registry?

Answer (score 1):

The respective documentation can be found in the [fabric8 'Registry handling'](http://maven.fabric8.io/#registry) chapter of the fabric8 documentation. For all options regarding setting (push- and pull-)registries, please refer to this manual. This answer will focus on the pushing registry setup.

**Instead of defining one registry for pushing and pulling** (as done in the question), there are **multiple push-only options**:

The **first option** is to use the **fabric8 "pushRegistry" configuration parameter** to *specify the AWS ECR registry*:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
  <configuration>
    ...
    <pushRegistry>your_aws_id.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com</pushRegistry>
    ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Of course you need to replace "your_aws_id" with your account id.

Or as **second option** you can set the `docker.push.registry` **system property** accordingly.

**A third option** is to *add the registry as part of the image name*.

For authentication you may want to check the [AWS ECR credential helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/tree/master) or this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49378313/4635513).